# Seeing nginx default page after django installation on digital ocean

Tags: postgresql, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I have been trying to deploy a product version of my django application. For that, I have been informed that I must follow the following tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04

to setup and run my application on nginx server using gunicorn. I followed all the steps and everything went fine. But in the end of this tutorial it says that:

> If no errors are reported, go ahead and restart Nginx by typing:
>
> `sudo service nginx restart`
>
> You should now be able to go to your
>   server's domain or IP address to view your application.

but when I go to my ip address, I see the default nginx page. Screen shot here:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7vVf.png)

Can anyone advise, what can I do to see my actual website from here by visiting my ip address in browser?

Comment: You **must** not follow the tutorial, there are several ways to setup nginx, gunicorn, postgres and django to work together.  You, on the other hand, **must** provide your configuration (making sure you are not making typos) for the components.  Notably, the entire nginx config, how you are starting gunicorn and whether gunicorn is listening on the desired socket.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting gunicorn service also. I would suggest using automated deployment methodology rather than manually doing it, like dokku, mina etc.